# Get nearest line to point with v.distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, point, line, distance

I want to retrieve the nearest line to a point with the GRASS function v.distance(). But I think I do not fully understand how to use this function. What I have are two layers (in the same CRS -> EPSG:31255): one point-layer which contains the locations of all my sensors and one line-layer which contains a streetnet. The following picture shows both my layers:
[image]

With v.distance, I want to retrieve the nearest line (street) for each point (sensor). Furthermore, I want to update my point-attribut "edgeid" with the id of the nearest line.
[image]

EVIS_Stat_Sensorik_.. is my point-layer and Reprojiziert is my line-layer.
For the upload string I used the "to_attr"-String because the relation between the pointlayer and the linelayer should not be based on the distance, but on the id of the nearest edge. So that the edgeid-attribut will get updated by the function and not some other attributs of the pointlayer.
For the "Column name where values specified by upload option.." I chose edgeid because the edgeid should get updated. 
For the "Column name of neariest feature.." I chose id, because the attribut edgeid  of the pointlayer should be updated WITH the id of the nearest line of the line layer.

But the problem is, if I run the algorithm, the output is a NEW pointlayer which is identical with the given input pointlayer EVIS_Stat_Sensorik_.. and the edgeid-attribut of BOTH the input and output pointlayer is still empty. So I do not understand where I can see the results of the algorithm. 
In the following picture you can se the attributtable of my output-linelayer named "Nearest":
[image]

I have looked through a lot threads and the duplicate questions do not help me either ([How to estimate distance from points to line feature with v.distance?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61676/how-to-estimate-distance-from-points-to-line-feature-with-v-distance) , [Nearest distance between point layer and line layer, QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181636/nearest-distance-between-point-layer-and-line-layer-qgis), [Finding nearest line to point in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59173/finding-nearest-line-to-point-in-qgis) ). Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the "threads" that you have looked through?  If they are Q&As on this site then please include links to them.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: @Temporalista Hey, I have solved the problem by using the NNJoin plugin! This performs a join operation (on the distance) of two layers (in my case, one point-layer and one line-layer. Hope this helps you too.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've also found a solution/bug: The id attribute to be joined must be type text (string). I'll post a full answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is not working for you. Can I suggest to try in GRASS itself, standalone. Once you have it working there, then switch back to the QGIS Processing framework.

Note that the output layer from `v.distance` is just the connector lines between the "from" points layer to the "to" lines layer. So assuming you have columns: "edgeid" in the points layer and "id" in the lines layer, and the columns are the same type (both text), then the command would be:

`v.distance from=<points> to=<lines> output=connectors upload=to_attr column=edgeid to_column=id`

After that completes, you should have the line "id" value of the closest line in the "edgeid" column for each point.

Answer (score 1):

The GRASS v.distance function did not use to work in QGIS Processing.  See
[GRASS v.distance in QGIS not working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73575/grass-v-distance-in-qgis-not-working).  According to https://issues.qgis.org/issues/5954 and https://issues.qgis.org/issues/12817, it should be fixed now.