# Fixed buffer remove overlayed area

Tags: qgis, buffer, overlay

I have a problem with a fixed layer.

I have to count accident by Link within 100m area.

When I use a Fixed Distance Buffer, there is a problem because some area is overlayed so they will count 1 accident to 2.

So I used the Node Tool.

I want to know is there any automatic way for this solution?

**Key:** All of the layers must not be overlayed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [v.distance](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass75/manuals/v.distance.html) from the GRASS tools to get the nearest road link to each accident point. The tool also lets you set a maximum distance (in your case 100m). This should give you lines from the points to the lines with ids for each. Now join the result to the accident attribute table and you should have what you need.

There are also some good pointers on how to use the tool in [this question/answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263508/get-nearest-line-to-point-with-v-distance-in-qgis)